# In the Fish shell, how can I join an array with a custom separator?

Tags: fish

I have an array whose elements may contain spaces:

```
set ASD "a" "b c" "d"
```

How can I convert this array to a single string of comma-separated values?

```
# what I want:
"a,b c,d"
```

So far the closest I could get was converting the array to a string and then replacing all the spaces. The problem is that this only works if the array elements don't contain spaces themselves

```
(echo $ARR | tr ' ' ',')
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since fish 2.3.0 you can use the `string` builtin:

```
string join ',' $ASD
```

---

The rest of this answer applies to older versions of fish.

One option is to use variable catenation:

```
echo -s ,$ASD
```

This adds an extra comma to the beginning. If you want to remove it, you can use `cut`:

```
echo -s ,$ASD | cut -b 2-
```

For completeness, you can also put it after and use `sed`:

```
echo -s $ASD, | sed 's/,$//'
```

Comment: Those `cut`/`sed` approaches only work if the elements of the array don't contain newline characters. `tail -c +2` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `printf` and `paste` instead of `echo` and `tr`:

```
printf '%s\n' $ASD | paste -sd,
```

AFAIK, `fish` has no builtin way for joining array elements.

Comment: not sure if it was added in the interim or before but the command to join array elements is `string join [(-q | --quiet)] SEP [STRING...]` - example: `string join \n $PATH`